# Xul element is not showing back after set it "hidden"

Tags: javascript, xul, xulrunner, xbl

**Updated**

Here's an even simpler example showing the failure (it should hide the img after press "z" and show it after press "x"):

**My test.xul:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://test/content/test.css" type="text/css"?>

<window id="desktop" width="640" height="480"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <image id="img" src="image.png" flex="1"/>

</window>
```

**My test.css:**

```
#desktop { -moz-binding: url("chrome://test/content/test.xml#desktop"); }
```

**My test.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<bindings xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
         xmlns:xbl="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
         xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <!-- Desktop binding & Key handlers -->
    <binding id="desktop">
        <handlers>
            <handler event="keypress" key="Z" >
                <![CDATA[
                    var img = getElementById("img");
                    if(img)
                        img.hidden = true;
                ]]>
            </handler>
            <handler event="keypress" key="X" >
                <![CDATA[
                    var img = getElementById("img");
                    if(img)
                        img.hidden = false;
                ]]>
            </handler>
        </handlers>
    </binding>

</bindings>
```

It's not showing back after hidden, any idea how to fix it? Is it a xulrunner bug? I'm running it with xulrunnet 1.9.2.12.

Comment: I'm not sure of understanding why are you using `visibility: collapse` instead of `visibility: hidden`

Comment: @Joel Alejandro the behavior is the same here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with Xulrunner 9.0.2.12, it works well with 9.0.2.10.

Answer (score 0):

Use
vbox.setAttribute("hidden", "true");
and
vbox.removeAttribute("hidden");

Comment: Or even just `vbox.hidden = true` , `vbox.hidden = false`

Comment: @MatrixFrog in my early days with XUL I fought a lot with the nuances between attributes and properties, I eventually settled into just using attributes, almost always.  You're probably right though. :-)

Comment: This variations are resulting the same behavior. I'll try to make a simple sample of a full app here and post it.